# Using the word discuss without the object

Tags: grammar, american-english, pronouns

> - Let's discuss this with him
> - Let's discuss with him

are both of them grammatically correct?

A grammar checker pointed out a flaw in "*Let's discuss with him*" and suggested adding "*this*" mentioning "correcting pronoun usage"

Comment: ***To discuss*** is rarely used intransitively in English, so although *strictly speaking* your usage is "syntactically valid", it's sufficiently "abnormal" for your grammar checker to question it. Most online dictionaries only define the *transitive* use, so that should have given you a clue that your grammar checker wasn't acting randomly.

Comment: Let's discuss. written at the bottom or in the margin of a memo. However, not in regular written English. with him only if the he is known to the parties.

Comment: English is less strict than some languages and it's often possible to elide the object of a transitive verb, especially in casual or note forms. You don't provide a context/style/register though - more appropriate in an IM than a formal letter.

Comment: @Lambie I like that example. Another idiomatic use of intransitive "discuss": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58grYzCcfHI (at 1:15 and 3:20)

Answer (score 0):

As [the comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332600/using-the-word-discuss-without-the-object#comment629945_332600) by FumbleFingers indicates, the verb "*discuss*" is usually used in a transitive sense in English, where the topic of discussion is mentioned, as in

> - Let's discuss the problem with him.
> - Let's discuss this with him.

That sort of use is the normal and common use of "discuss".

It is possible to use that verb intransitively, as in:

> Let's discuss with him.

that usage is grammatically valid, and is used under some circumstances. The meaning is slightly different, as that form indicates a general discussion, or perhaps that the subject was previously mentioned and is already known to the listener.
This usage is acceptable, but is significantly less common among fluent speakers.

Comment: I wish that any downvoters would leave a comment indicting what they think is wrong with this answer. In the absence of a comment, I cannot improve the answer, others cannot use the reasons to write better answers, and readers have no idea why someone objects to the answer. Such a downvote seems pointless.